# How do you reference the models repository in Azure Machine Learning from within side a python script step?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I know there's a $MODEL_VERSION variable when you create a scoring script using AKS but how about for a script task (example python script task) but I can't find documentation on how to deserialize a model into object from within script step running on a Linux AML computer cluster.

Is there a way to use models I've published to models tab in Workspace (say name is my model) from within a python script step?

For example in this code snippet:

```
import job lib
model = joblib.load(file_path + "mymodel")
```

I'm looking for what relative or absolute NIX path to use for file_path during a run where mymodel has already been published to the Workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You can interact with the registered models via the [AML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py).

Considering that you have the SDK installed/authenticated, or that you are running this on an AML compute, you can use the following code to get the workspace:

```
from azureml.core import Workspace, Model
ws = Workspace.from_config()
```

Once you have the workspace, you can list all the models:

```
for model in Model.list(ws):
    print(model.name, model.version)
```

And for a specific model, you can get the path and load it back to memory with joblib:

```
import joblib
model_path = Model.get_model_path(model_name = 'RegressionDecisionTree', version = 1, _workspace= ws)
model_obj = joblib.load(model_path)
```